# Can you disable UNC paths in Windows?

Tags: windows, path, unc

We are trying to lock down a Terminal Server, and want to remove a commercial package's ability to accept UNC file paths, ie. paths in the app can then only be entered using the windows drive letters.

Is there any way to do this in Windows?

Can we disallow UNC paths for just the app?

Can we disallow UNC paths for the entire Terminal Server session?

The intention is to allow the application to only write to certain directories (as mapped in the Terminal Server session). The aim is to prevent the output of files to directories that the users have access to, but are not mapped in the Terminal Server session.

Answer (score 0):

According to windowsitpro.com,

> You must edit the NoRun value (of type
>   DWORD) in the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   or
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   registry subkey.

http://windowsitpro.com/Articles/Print.cfm?ArticleID=25421

But as Richard said, this is more of a serverfault.com question.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the GPO under User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Start Menu and Task Bar>Remove Run menu from Start Menu (enabled or disabled?).

This prevents the user from entering in a unc path in IE address bar if enabled